# In R, how to read an index vector?

Tags: r

*Example.
I have two vectors, vec_1 and vec_2

```
vec_1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
ver_2 <- c(6,7)
I want to do
vec = vector()
for(i in 1:2){
vec[i] <- mean(vec_i)
}**
```

I already tested "paste" of various types. Help!*

Comment: Do you need `lapply(mget(paste0("vec_", 1:2)), mean)`

Comment: Thank you. Perfect!

Comment: Hi! Sorry. vec_1, vec_2, are data frames, I need to access a column named pressure lapply(mget(paste("vec_",1:10,"$Pressure")), mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values of the objects in a `list`, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, get the `mean`

```
lapply(mget(paste0("vec_", 1:2)), mean)
```

If it is a `data.frame`

```
lapply(mget(paste0('vec_', 1:10)), function(x) mean(x$Pressure))
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!